# Dynamic adjacency list from 2D array

Tags: c++, pointers, graph, adjacency-list

I need to creat a dynamically allocated adjacency list of a graph, given the 40x20 2D array of 0's and 1's. The graph is rectangular, and edges are created only when two vertices are directly adjacent, meaning a vertex can only have a maximum of 4 neighbouring vertices. Here's some code i was toying with, but i can't really understand how to feed the function a formal parameter that looks like this

```
Vertex** Wierzch; //Wierzch == vertex in my language
```

Here's my code so far, I was able to write a program that creates a graph determined by the users input, however in the next step I will try to create a graph that connects vertices that are 1's

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;


struct Vertex
{
  int var;
  Vertex * next;
};

int main( )
{
  int n, m, i, v1, v2;
  Vertex ** Wierzch;
  Vertex *p, *r;

  cin >> n >> m;    

  Wierzch = new Vertex* [n]; 

  for( i = 0; i < n; i++ ) 
  Wierzch[i] = NULL;

  for( i = 0; i < m; i++ )
  {
    cin >> v1 >> v2;  
    p = new Vertex;  
    (*p).var = v2; 
    (*p).next = Wierzch[v1]; 
    Wierzch[v1] = p;
  }

  cout << endl;


  for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
  {
    cout << "Wierzch [" << i << "] =";
    p = Wierzch[i];
    while(p)
    {
      cout << setw ( 3 ) << p->var;
      p = p->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
  }

  for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
  {
    p = Wierzch[i];
    while( p )
    {
      r = p;
      p = p->next;
      delete r;
    }
  }

  delete [] Wierzch;

  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Here's how i would like it to look in the final form, as it's just a part of a bigger project, I can't have it working only in `int(main)` , but as i said i don't know what Vertex** Wierzch really represents.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct Vertex{
    int var = 0;
    bool colour; // false = black, true = white  
    Vertex* next;
};

void CreateList(Vertex **& Wierzch);
void DeleteList(Vertex **& Wierzch);
void PrintList(Vertex **& Wierzch);

void CreateList(Vertex **& Wierzch, int& m, int& n)
{

    Vertex* p;
    int v1, v2;
    
    cin >> m >> n; // Number of vertexes and edges respectively
    
    Wierzch = new Vertex* [m];

    for(int i = 0;i<m;i++)
    Wierzch[i] = NULL;
    
    for(int i = 0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin >> v1 >> v2;
        p = new Vertex;
        p->var = v2;
        p->next = Wierzch[v1];
        Wierzch[v1] = p;    
    }   
        
}

void PrintList(Vertex **& Wierzch, int& m)
{
    Vertex* p;
    for(int i = 0;i<m;i++)
    {
        cout << "Wierzch [" << i << "]=";
        p = Wierzch[i];
    }
    while(p)
    {
        cout << setw(3) << p->var;
        p= p->next;
    }
}

void DeleteList(Vertex **& Wierzch, int& m)
{
    Vertex* r, *p;
    for(int i =0;i<m;i++)
    {
        p = Wierzch[i];
        while(p)
        {
            r = p;
            p = p->next;
            delete r;
        }
        
    delete [] Wierzch;  
    }
}

int main()
{
    int m =0, n = 0;
        Vertex** Wierzch;
    CreateList(Wierzch, m, n);
    PrintList(Wierzch, m);
    DeleteList(Wierzch, m);
    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, especially what the `Vertex** Wierzch` really is and how to give it as a formal parameter to any function that would work on it.

Comment: dynamic arrays are called `std::vector`. There is a way to deal with this `**` madness, but for your own sanity rather use `std::vector` or another container

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Hi, unfortunately this is a school project and i cant use STL libraries, that including vector. STL and usage of libs like vector is the theme of my next project, however i cant use them here unfortunately :/